# Skew and crop image on one side

Tags: html, css, transform

Is there a way to make image looking like this:

[image]

To make look like this with css:

[image]

I've tried skew but I just can't get rid of the red area, it's always there, whatever degree value I use.

My basic structure is like following:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="trapec">
        <div class="image"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

For styling I used something like this here: http://jsfiddle.net/mXLgF/477/

My CSS:

```
.wrapper  {
        width: 530px;
        background: rgba(180, 180, 180, 0.7);
        position: relative;
        height: 230px;
    }

.wrapper .trapec{
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        width: 325px;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        -webkit-transform: skew(20deg);
        -moz-transform: skew(20deg);
        -o-transform: skew(20deg);
    }

    .wrapper .trapec .image {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg);
       -moz-transform: skew(-20deg);
         -o-transform: skew(-20deg);
        background: url("../img/news_img.jpg") no-repeat center / cover;
    }
```

I've tried many degree values but the red line just won't go away.
Please help.

Comment: Please include more of your CSS here, something that produces what we see in the images. Thanks.

Comment: @Mooseman done, please see "MY CSS"

Comment: Not using CSS clip.  Normally you should use something like php and GD if you want to modify an image (especially permanently).  If what you are doing is simply masking then you could have a prepared png with a white mask and background transparent which you overlay on your image.  I don't know why this would be better than modifying the image in an image editing programme though.  What's the aim of what you are trying to achieve?  IS the image your own image/on your server?

Comment: @garrettlynch the idea is that content manager will upload through Wordpress normal rectangular images and they should be cropped by css or other means. Hope my aim is clear.

Comment: @kulan you can use the `:after` pseudo css. I have added a solution below for this

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:before` pseudo css. And I will recommend to use `<img>` tag instead of `background-image`.

Adjust the `skew()` value according to your requirement.

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bhuwanb9/2nc0uwnk/)**

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

#parallelogram {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

#parallelogram:after {
  content: "";
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  transform: skew(30deg);
  transform-origin: bottom;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="parallelogram">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/sports" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```